# Trouble with using protected enum class from base class as public enum class in derived class [MSVC 2019]

Tags: c++, visual-c++

We're having a situation like below.

We're trying to access a `protected` nested `enum class` from outside the class that contains it, through a derived class by declaring this same enumeration `public` in the derived class through the use of the `using` keyword.

We're using the MSVC2019 compiler and the below code doesn't compile. It results in a C2248 error stating that we cannot access the protected enum. I've tried with GCC as well, and then it seems to compile just fine, like I expected it to.

I was hoping there's someone out there that might be able to explain on this?

Not looking for a workaround though, that we already found.

```
#include <iostream>

class Base
{
protected:
  enum class Field
  {
    A,
    B
  };

};

class Derived :
  public Base
{
public:
  using Base::Field;

  Derived(Field f);
  
};

Derived::Derived(Field f) {  
  switch (f)
  {
  case Field::A:
    std::cout << "A" << std::endl;
    break;
    
  case Field::B:
    std::cout << "B" << std::endl;
    break;
  }
}

int main()
{
  Derived d(Derived::Field::B);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: C++ is the most complicated general purpose programming language in use today. It is not uncommon to find some corner cases that produce different results by different compilers. Here, it seems that the MSVC compiler is getting this wrong. That's all there is to it, nothing more.

Comment: clang-cl in Visual Studio is happy with your code, too. Agree with @Sam - MSVC is wrong. BTW, is this your workaround: `using Field = Base::Field;`?

Comment: [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration) says: *Only the name explicitly mentioned in the using-declaration is transferred into the declarative scope: in particular, enumerators are not transferred when the enumeration type name is using-declared.*. So by that I would think MSVS is correct, but I don't have the time to dig into the standard to find out.

Comment: @AdrianMole Thanks for the suggested workaround, didn't think of that one! It's actually nicer than the one we have now. We've worked around it using a friend class which for the code it concerned that was acceptable. Your solution is definitely better though.